# Finding the longest substring regex?

Tags: c#, regex, algorithm

Someone knows how to find the longest substring  composed of letters using using MatchCollection.

```
public static Regex pattern2 = new Regex("[a-zA-Z]");
public static string zad3 = "ala123alama234ijeszczepsa";
```

Comment: `Regex.Matches` returns all matches, scan them and get the longest one

Comment: Regex.Matches don't work for regex

Comment: @tomkarnaski that's inherently a false statement. What do you mean by "don't work"?

Comment: Using a regex is not a performant attempt to find the longest substring composed of letters. I would iterate the letters and keep track on the longst sequence seen so far. Takes **O(n)** (n= length of the string).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can loop over all matches and get the longest:

```
string max = "";

foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(zad3, "[a-zA-Z]+"))
    if (max.Length < match.Value.Length)
        max = match.Value;
```

Comment: Be explicit in the foreach loop, `foreach (Match match in ...`

Comment: @TomKarnaski As I mentioned!

Answer (score 1):

Using `linq` and the short one:

```
string longest= Regex.Matches(zad3, pattern2).Cast<Match>()
.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value.Length).FirstOrDefault()?.Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 MatchCollection matches = pattern2.Matches(txt);
 List<string> strLst = new List<string>();
 foreach (Match match in matches)
     strLst.Add(match.Value);
 var maxStr1 = strLst.OrderByDescending(s => s.Length).First();
```

or better way :

```
 var maxStr2 = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray().OrderByDescending(s => s.Length).First();
```

Answer (score 1):

best solution for your task is:

```
string zad3 = "ala123alama234ijeszczepsa54dsfd";
string max = Regex.Split(zad3,@"\d+").Max(x => x);
```

Answer (score 1):

You must change your Regex pattern to include the repetition operator `+` so that it matches more than once.

`[a-zA-Z]` should be `[a-zA-Z]+`

You can get the longest value using LINQ. Order by the match length descending and then take the first entry. If there are no matches the result is `null`.

```
string pattern2 = "[a-zA-Z]+";
string zad3 = "ala123alama234ijeszczepsa";

var matches = Regex.Matches(zad3, pattern2);

string result = matches
                 .Cast<Match>()
                 .OrderByDescending(x => x.Value.Length)
                 .FirstOrDefault()?
                 .Value;
```

The string named `result` in this example is:

> ijeszczepsa

Answer (score -1):

you can find it in O(n) like this (if you do not want to use regex):

```
string zad3 = "ala123alama234ijeszczepsa";
int max=0;
int count=0;
for (int i=0 ; i<zad3.Length ; i++)
{
    if (zad3[i]>='0' && zad3[i]<='9')
    {   
        if (count > max)
            max=count;
        count=0;
        continue;
    }
    count++;                
}

if (count > max)
    max=count;

Console.WriteLine(max);
```

Comment: all your code in one line : Regex.Split(zad3,@"\d+").Max(x => x); (max, count, if, continue ... why ??)

Comment: Regex.Split is used KMP in O(n+k) and my code is simple implementation of KMP without any regex. So it is a little faster than  Regex.Split with regex.

Comment: I think it’s not the case where you need to worry about the performance but i get your point